# CSS fluid and fixed columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have table, for example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td class="fixed">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

for example my table width is 800px.

all first two columns must be fluid, but last: fixed...

how could i do this?

also what would be if my first two columns are very small? how to attach fixed to right? (also height is fluid)

Comment: .fixed{ width: 250px; }  should this do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please attach a demo (like a jsFiddle).

Comment: @Crispy-George no) that why i'm asking

Comment: @Dura http://jsfiddle.net/jozzh4oo/

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Check your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jozzh4oo/1/). you need to use percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `<table>` gets `table-layout: fixed`; this will allow the third column to remain its fixed width
- The table also gets a `max-width: 800px` and `width: 100%`; it will resize
- We place three [`<col>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) inside the table to represent the columns; the third column gets our class with `width: 250px`

#### Complete Example

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed {
  width: 250px;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col class="fixed">
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking with: "also what would be if my first two columns are very small? how to attach fixed to right?"

Comment: i mean what would be max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%; and first two td would be empty?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 - The fluid width columns would be hidden if the fixed width column were the same (or greater) width as the tables max width. The fixed width column would have to be a decent size smaller than the tables max width for this not to occur.